# Change right-click settings to highlight more than just 1 word

Tags: macos, text, contextual-menu

I am trying to change the default settings for right-clicking text in macOS. By default, the word that is being hovered over is selected/highlighted and the contextual menu appears, however, I would like the right-click to select everything until it finds a space and open the contextual menu.

For example, if I have a file path:

```
/volumes/share/myfolder/image1.png
```

If I right click over volumes it will highlight "volumes", I would like it to highlight the entire path, including the file extension. In essence, I want it to treat / and . as letters when deciding what to highlight when I right-click.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is some application that can trigger a script on a mouse click, like usb overdrive (should work). The script should simulate a triple click and a right click... Not sure if that is worth trying though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the concept of a triple click is exactly the functionality required I think but I use an Apple magic mouse so it will not work for me. [see here](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/Information.html)

Comment: I think there may be two options. If you use Sierra, maybe [Smooze](https://smooze.co/) They don't specifically say it doesn't support magic mouse so maybe that would work. The script would have to be triggered via a shortcut. If you are using one of the older mac versions, [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) can definitely do it. Sadly if you're using Sierra, it won't have the functionality, as the Sierra version is in early stages.